# guard let - Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm currently just playing around with swift. I'm following a Lynda.com watch kit tutorial that walks viewers through creating a simple watch calculator.

The following method is throwing the error "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'"

```
 func updateText(){
         guard let labelInt:Int64 = Int64(labelString) else {
             label.setText("Number is too big")
             return
         }
         label.setText("\(labelInt)")
     }
```

For some reason xCode isn't recognizing guard and therefor the statement is throwing errors. I've seen multiple tutorials using guard, what am I missing? The tutorial appears to use the exact same method character-to-character without issue.

Entire file for reference:

```
 import WatchKit
 import Foundation

 class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

     var labelString:String = "0"

     @IBOutlet var label: WKInterfaceLabel!
     @IBAction func tapped0(){tappedNumber(0)}
     @IBAction func tapped1(){tappedNumber(1)}
     @IBAction func tapped2(){tappedNumber(2)}
     @IBAction func tapped3(){tappedNumber(3)}
     @IBAction func tapped4(){tappedNumber(4)}
     @IBAction func tapped5(){tappedNumber(5)}
     @IBAction func tapped6(){tappedNumber(6)}
     @IBAction func tapped7(){tappedNumber(7)}
     @IBAction func tapped8(){tappedNumber(8)}
     @IBAction func tapped9(){tappedNumber(9)}

     func tappedNumber(num:Int){
         labelString = labelString.stringByAppendingString("\(num)")
         updateText()
     }

     func updateText(){
         guard let labelInt:Int64 = Int64(labelString) else {
             label.setText("Number is too big")
             return
         }
         label.setText("\(labelInt)")
     }

     @IBAction func tappedPlus(){

     }
     @IBAction func tappedMinus(){

     }
     @IBAction func tappedClear(){

     }
     @IBAction func tappedEquals(){

     }

     override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
         super.awakeWithContext(context)

         // Configure interface objects here.
     }

     override func willActivate() {
         // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
         super.willActivate()
     }

     override func didDeactivate() {
         // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
         super.didDeactivate()
     }

 }
```

Comment: Are you using Swift  1.x / Xcode 6 or Swift 2 / Xcode 7? The `guard` expression is available only in Swift2

Comment: Im using Xcode 6.4 and am still new enough that I don't know how to check what version of swift I'm using.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up a terminal command. This is the problem, i'm running 1.2

Comment: Xcode 6 uses Swift 1.2. (no `guard` statement). Xcode 7 is available on the App Store

Comment: Thanks, If you want to make this the official answer I'll accept it and leave my question for others.

Answer (score 1):

The `guard` expression is available only in Swift 2 / Xcode 7

The final version of Xcode 7 has been released a few days ago (Sept. 17)